# property length does not exist on type Object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a services that get's a JSON from docker. I want to get the amount of containers.

So I subscribe to my service:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.docker.getContainers().subscribe(containers => {
        console.log(containers.length);
    });
}
```

I get the right answer on the console and yet I get:

> property length does not exist on type Object

Am I doing something wrong?

```
export class DockerService {
  private baseUrl:string = 'http://localhost:8080/api/docker';
  private headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
  private options = new HttpHeaderResponse({headers:this.headers});

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }

  getContainers() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/containers", this.options);
  }

  getImages() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/images", this.options);
  }
}
```

Comment: please show the `containers`

Comment: edited. that's my docker service

Comment: `console.log` only `containers`

Comment: I get an array of 5 elements. it's right.

Comment: Please read [how to make reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I will put the json

Comment: Which Http service are you currently using? the old `Http` or the newer `HttpClient`?

Comment: HttpClient. I'm using Angular 6

Comment: @user9793665 can you post the return json in `containers`?

Answer (score 12):

You should use **(containers: any[])** when declaring the var:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.docker.getContainers().subscribe((containers: any[]) => {
        console.log(containers.length);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since by default the HttpClient gets the response as an Object it does not have those properties. You can declare the containers as **any[]** and access the length property.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.docker.getContainers().subscribe(containers : any[] => {
    console.log(containers.length);
});
}
```

So change the code as above and it would work

Answer (score 3):

Basically angular does not know which type is returned by your http call, therefore it autocasts it into an object, which has no `length` value. In order for it to work, you have to typecast it to what you are expecting it to be, in your example probably an array of Containers.

```
getContainers(): Container[] {
  return this._http.get<Container[]>(this.baseUrl + "/containers", this.options);
 }
```

This way angular will know what to expect and the attributes should exist. This of course depends on the `Container` class, which you probably don't have. Cleanest way would be to create this class and define its attributes to what is coming back from the backend.

However if for some reason you don't want to do this, you can probably just tell angular that you're expecting an array of `any`, which does not provide the type safety, but at least you'll have your `length attribute`.

```
getContainers(): any[] {
  return this._http.get<any[]>(this.baseUrl + "/containers", this.options);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**3/24/2019**

**Angular-7**

I get Solution by using... `Observable<any[]>`

**Example:**

```
getContainers(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this._http.get<any[]>(this.baseUrl + "/containers", this.options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should map your response, try this:

```
getContainers() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/containers", this.options).map(res => {
                return res.json();
            });
}



getImages() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/images", this.options).map(res => {
                return res.json();
            });
}
```

Comment: It depends on which version of angular OP is using , for higher versions and with new HTTP Client `res.json()` is not required

Comment: property json does not exist on type Object

Comment: I'm using Angular 6. I tried `return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/containers", this.options).pipe(map(res => {
      return res.json();
    }));`

Comment: @user9793665 in angular 6 res.json() is not required you by default get json .. just check whether it's an Object or an array.

Comment: it's an object.

Comment: then it would not work you have to access the property of the object whose value is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Object does not have property like length but object has key value pair and there will be finite keys in an object so we can invoke length property on keys of object. I tried the following way and it worked for me.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.docker.getContainers().subscribe((containers: any[]) => {
        console.log(Object.keys(containers).length);
    });
}
```